# Очистка текста Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Мне нужно удалить текст между символами (два варианта). Текст такого вида:

```
TEST """111111> TEST1
TEST """222222>> TEST2
TEST """333>>> TEST3
TEST "444444>>> TEST4
TEST ""5555>>> TEST5
```

Чтобы на выходе получилось:

**Вариант 1** (Только текст а символы оставить):

```
TEST """> TEST1
TEST """>> TEST2
TEST """>>> TEST3
TEST ">>> TEST4
TEST "">>> TEST5
```

**Вариант 2** (Включительно с символами):

```
TEST TEST1
TEST TEST2
TEST TEST3
TEST TEST4
TEST TEST4
```

Уточнение: **Имеется в виду удалить текст между:**

```
""" и этим >
""" и этим >>
""" и этим >>>
"   и этим >>>
""  и этим >>>
```

Вариант 1 - оставить символы а удалить только текст между символами.

Вариант 2 - удалить символы и текст который находиться между символами.

**После обработки кодом который вот у меня:**

// В edit указываю между чем и чем удалить

```
Len := Length(S);
  Pos1 := 0;
for P := Len downto 1 do
begin
  if (S[P] = edit3.text) and (Pos1 = 0) then
  begin
    Pos1 := P;
  end;
  if (S[P] = edit2.text) and (Pos1 <> 0) then
  begin
    Delete(S, P, Pos1 - P + 1);
    Pos1 := 0;
  end;
```

У меня получается вот такой результат (То есть часть символов остаеться):

```
TEST "" TEST1
TEST "" TEST2
TEST "" TEST3
TEST TEST4
TEST " TEST5
```

Comment: Тут с терминологией проблемы. Вероятно задание звучит: Вариант 1. удалить все цифры.  Вариант 2. оставить только буквы и пробелы

Comment: @JaponDemon, Я привела пример текста - который может быть между символами. А задача поставлена правильно.

Comment: `TEST T>ES_T2 TEST4` что нужно будет удалить отсюда? Сформулируйте требования по удалению

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Внесла поправку в тему как Вы сказали.

Comment: Вы написали что вам нужно, но вы забыли написать вопрос. Что у вас не получается, чем/как мы можем вам помочь в формате ruSO?

Comment: А помните вам про регулярные выражения ссылки давали? Вот если бы вы поняли их(регулрные выражения) Этого вопроса бы небыло

Comment: @Kromster, Привела код которым обрабатываю и отредактировала тему - посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Т.е. у вас два ограничителя `"` и `>`. И в первом случае вам нужно удалить текст между первым знаком `>` и ближайшем к нему слева знака `"`. А во втором - между первым знаком `"` и последним знаком `>`. Так?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Да.

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov вопрос решила и ответила в тему. Может и не сильно эффективно но работает. Если будут еще у вас варианты то напишите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решила вот таким способом.

```
// поиск первого вхождения символа
function LastSymbolPos(const C: Char; const s: string): integer;
var
  i: DWORD;
begin
  Result:= 0;
  for i:= Length(s) downto 1 do
  if s[i] = C then
  begin
    Result:= i;
    Break;
  end;
end;

// поиск последнего вхождения символа
function FirstSymbolPos(const C: Char; const s: string): integer;
var
  i: DWORD;
begin
  Result:= 0;
  for i:= 1 to Length(s) do
  if s[i] = C then
  begin
    Result:= i;
    Break;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,a,b: byte;
  s: string;
begin
  Memo2.Lines.Add('Вариант 1');
  for i:= 0 to Pred(Memo1.Lines.Count) do
  begin
    s:= Memo1.Lines[i];
    a:= LastSymbolPos('"',s)+1;
    b:= FirstSymbolPos('>',s);
    Delete(s,a,b-a);
    Memo2.Lines.Add(s);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,a,b: byte;
  s: string;
begin
  Memo2.Lines.Add('Вариант 2');
  for i:= 0 to Pred(Memo1.Lines.Count) do
  begin
    s:= Memo1.Lines[i];
    a:= FirstSymbolPos('"',s);
    b:= LastSymbolPos('>',s)+1;
    Delete(s,a,b-a);
    Memo2.Lines.Add(s);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `FirstSymbolPos` можно заменить стандартной `Pos()`

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Сделала, всегда приятно когда в моих темах - люди помогают и подсказывают.

Comment: Я не знаю, как в ХЕ, а в ХЕ3 можно писать так `s.IndexOf('"')`, `s.LastIndexOf('>')`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov в XE2 так все еще нельзя к сожалению.

Comment: А ещё есть [LastDelimeter](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_LastDelimiter.html) и [StrRScan](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_StrRScan@PAnsiChar@AnsiChar.html), но свой велосипед всегда прикольнее, я тоже так иногда делаю :)